# How do you manipulate urls in asp.net WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, url

I need a class to manipulate URLs in asp.net WebForms

eg

```
Url url = new Url("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

if(!url.Params.Contains("user"))
  url.Params.Add("user", "1");
```

I have tried NameValueCollections but they seem to be readonly as do a number of objects in HttpContext

```
NameValueCollection nv = Request.QueryString;

nv.Remove("ForeignLanguage");
nv.Add("ForeignLanguage", l.ID.ToString());
```

The above generates a Collection is readonly exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the [`UriBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tf6x8z6.aspx) class, in conjunction with the very handy [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) method:

```
var uri = new UriBuilder("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
NameValueCollection parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);
parameters.Add("user", "1");
uri.Query = parameters.ToString();
return uri.ToString();
```

Note the trick with passing an empty string to the `ParseQueryString` method - this will give you a (writable) instance of `System.Web.HttpValueCollection`, a non-public class that derives from `NameValueCollection` and (among other things) emits its contents in querystring format when you call its `ToString` method.

You could also manipulate the current url:

```
var uri = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
NameValueCollection parameters = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
// TODO Manipulate parameters...
uri.Query = parameters.ToString();
return uri.ToString();
```